# Geom_mosaic - How to add the variences labels to the axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have this database:

[image: Database]

I've tried to make a geom_mosaic graph.
This is my code:

```
    ggplot(data) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(substanceabuse,probation),fill=substanceabuse))
```

and this is the result:

[image: Current graph]

How do I add the 'Yes' and 'No' labels as I got from the mosaicplot function:
[mosaicplot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHtLO.png)

Thanks ahead!

Comment: See [this thread](https://github.com/haleyjeppson/ggmosaic/issues/41)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `geom_mosaic()` has some bugs. I would suggest an approach of this style. Maybe can be useful for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
data <- data.frame(ClientId=1:6,
                   substanceabuse=rep(c('Yes','No'),each=3),
                   probation=c('No',rep('Yes',3),rep('No',2)),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
data %>% group_by(substanceabuse,probation) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(cut.count = sum(count),
         prop = count/sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = substanceabuse, y = prop, width = cut.count, fill = probation)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + # if labels are desired
  facet_grid(~substanceabuse, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Which in some sense is close to what you want.